# git merge --allow-unrelated-histories replicates commits in all branches

Tags: git

I have 2 repos, that need to be merged into a single repository.
Repo A, has repo B added as a remote.
In repo A, i have a `master` branch. For each branch of repo B, i'm creating  new branch, splintering off from repo A's `master` so:

```
git checkout -b new-branch;
```

Now i want to merge a repo B branch (doesn't matter which one), into my newly created branch in repo A so:

```
git merge repoB/branch --allow-unrelated-histories -m "some commit message";
```

After this, i have a problem. The changes in `new-branch` are also replicated into `master`.

The problem does not occur if i'm starting `orphan` branches from `master`.

This problem is further exacerbated if there's a third repository into the mix, since i can't start with orphan branches after the first merge.

What am i missing? How can i merge each branch from repo B, into a branch from repo A, while keeping the commit history?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this problem.  It also doesn't make any sense that this would occur for a branch `fetch`ed from another repo but not for an orphan branch created locally; as far as merge is concerned they're the same. I'd double-check that you executed the commands you meant to execute

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger turns out you're right, there's an issue with how i'm referencing the branches in the script that i've build. Manually it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Works as expected, there was an issue on my end.